# Customer Login API /login/token/{token} is not working as expected in Bigcommerce

Tags: api, jwt, single-sign-on, bigcommerce, headless

I am facing an issue while using Customer Login API '**/login/token/{jWT_token}**' in react app backing by Bigcommerce APIs.

Once a Customer login via API endpoint '/login/token/{token}', then his cart items (persistent cart) are not syncing. 
On the other side, if Customer is login directly via storefront login page then its working fine (cart item visible as expected).

Any help regarding this would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Persistent Cart is not supported in BigCommerce's interesting implementation.  We were able to circumvent this issue by using the server to server API and updating the current session cart with the customer ID before initiating the SSO.  You already likely have to run the GET ALL against customers to pull the ID value for SSO, this is just one more step.

> Does Persistent Cart work with Single Sign-on (SSO) providers that allow shoppers to log in through social identity (such as Google or Facebook) and enterprise identity providers?
>
> Blockquote SSO is currently not supported.

Of Note:  It is also not possible in their Wordpress Headless Approach.

See FAQ Section: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Persistent-Cart